# Unable to connect to Xerox B205 printer and print to it through Wi-Fi. Can connect to scan without issue

Tags: windows-10, printer

I've a Xerox B205 printer and my PC (Windows 10) has difficulties connecting to it through Wi-Fi.

In Xerox Easy Printer Manager I can connect to it and scan without any issues, however for printing it appears offline on the same PC.

After pressing power button several times (to wake up from sleep) or scanning something, it's generally resolved, however it's pretty annoying.

Is there any way to fix this issue?

I've already tried removing and adding it again, but it haven't solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Likely the issue is that laser printers have *powerful* heaters to fuse the toner. To save power, the heater shuts down between uses. If you wait a few minutes. There is also a setting for *timeout*, to log out the active user. Summarized from the [Xerox B205 manual](https://www.manualslib.com/manual/1997724/Xerox-B205.html), which you should consult for *any* issues:

- "When the printer does not receive data for an extended period of time... power consumption is automatically lowered." To change that timeout:

  1. Press the **Machine Status** button on the control panel.
  2. Press the Up/Down arrows to select **System Setup** and press **OK**.
  3. Press the Up/Down arrows to select **Machine Setup** and press **OK**.
  4. Select **Power Saver Timers** to set the time the printer waits before entering **Low Power Save** or **Very Low Power Save**. Enter
     between 0 - 119 minutes.

**N.B.:** Increasing the heater timeout will increase electricity usage, will heat the room, and might shorten the operating life of the heater.

- Change how long the printer waits to log out an inactive user.

  1. In Xerox® CentreWare® Internet Services, click **Properties > Security**.
  2. Click **System Timeout**.
  3. For **Local User Interface System Timer**, enter the time that the printer waits before it... logs out inactive users.
  4. For **Web System Timer**, enter the amount of time the system waits before it... logs out inactive users from the *Web User Interface*.
  5. Click Apply.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I know increasing timer would also increase energy consumption. Is there a way to make connection quicker when the printer is in power saving mode?

Comment: The timeout for *inactivating* a user can be set. If you are the only user, there may be little downside to leaving the connection up permanently (or a t least a very long time). The heater will still need to warm up, though, to print.

Comment: The printer should automatically come out of power save when it receives data, you should not have to press the power button, or prevent it from going to sleep.

Answer (score 1):

I would try resetting the printer to factory defaults. According to the [User Guide](https://www.support.xerox.com/en-us/content/145400), do this:

1. In Xerox® CentreWare® Internet Services, click Status  General.
2. Click Network Factory Default. A warning message is displayed.
3. To confirm, click OK.

To access CentreWare® Internet Services, type it's IP address into your browser.